# How to iterate changing values onkeyup using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem in my jquery/code where the id's capturing with my jquery code is an array.

Here's the snippet code.
Here's my jquery.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').keyup(function()
    {

        $('.total_fabi').each(function() {
        var answer = parseFloat($('.req').val()) * parseInt($('.was_perc').val());
            $('.total_fabi').html(answer);
        });

    });
});
```

---

Here's the html generated code.

```
<table align='center' width='100%' border='1'>
<thead style='background-color: #900; color: #FFF;'>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Estimated Cost</th>
    <th>Req'd Qty</th>
    <th>Wastage %</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- This values are SQL generated inside While.. -->
    <!-- Values generated by sql are under Description, Estimated Cost, Wastage-->
    <!-- i Need to calculate the total using keyup by multiplying req'd qty * wastage% -->
    <tr bgcolor='#FFF'> 
        <td>FABRICATION PER LM</td>
        <td align='center'>200</td>
        <td align='center'><input type='text' size='3' name='req[]'  class='req'></td>
        <td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='was_perc[]' value='7' class='was_perc'>7</td>
        <td align='right'>
            <font color='#900'>
                <span id='total_fabi'>0</span>
                <input type='hidden' name='total_fabi' id='total_fabi' style='border: none;' size='6' readonly='readonly'>
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor='#E3E4FA'>  
        <td>INSTALLATION PER LM</td>
        <td align='center'>200</td>
        <td align='center'><input type='text' size='3' name='req[]'  class='req'></td>
        <td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='was_perc[]' value='15' class='was_perc'>15</td>
        <td align='right'>
            <font color='#900'>
                <span class='total_fabi'>0</span>
                <input type='hidden' name='total_fabi' id='total_fabi' style='border: none;' size='6' readonly='readonly'>
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Here's the while Ends..--->
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4' align='right'>Total Fabrication & Installation</td>
        <td align='right'>
            <!-- This part where $total+=$total_fabi -->
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

Here's the actual PHP code.

```
<table align='center' width='100%' border='1'>
                            <thead style='background-color: #900; color: #FFF;'>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Estimated Cost</th>
                                <th>Req'd Qty</th>
                                <th>Wastage %</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $total_non = 0;
                                $sel_fabi = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbllabor") or die (mysql_error());
                                while($non = mysql_fetch_array($sel_fabi)){
                                    $desc_fabi = $non['desc'];
                                    $est_cost = $non['est_cost'];
                                    $was_perc = $non['wastage_perc'];
                                    $was_perc = $was_perc * 100;
                                    //$total_fabi = $req * $was_perc;

                                echo "<tr bgcolor='".$colors[$c++ % 2]."'>";
                                echo "  <td>$desc_fabi</td>
                                        <td align='center'>$est_cost</td>
                                        <td align='center'><input type='text' size='3' name='req[]' class='req'></td>
                                        <td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='was_perc[]' value='$was_perc' class='was_perc'>$was_perc</td>
                                        <td align='right'>
                                            <font color='#900'>
                                            <span class='total_fabi'>0</span>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='total_fabi' id='total_fabi' style='border: none;' size='6' readonly='readonly'>
                                            </font>
                                        </td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan='4' align='right'>Total Fabrication & Installation</td>
                                    <td align='right'>
                                        <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $total_non;?>'>
                                        <?php echo $total_non;?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>   
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

---

.each() function is not working with me. with this kind of code i stated. do you have any other option where i should use keyup or keydown to calculate the total i needed.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID and iterate over them. Use classes.

Comment: First of all you need to know that ID attribute must be unique and you defined same ID many time.

Comment: @ user2593560: Please don't completely change the question once you've posted it. Your original used `id` values and multiple answers were provided on that basis. It is **not cool** to come back 10 minutes later and change something fundamental about the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` values [**must** be unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), you can't have more than one element with the same `id`. That's the fundamental problem.

You can change your `id` values to `class` values instead.

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but if the goal is to update the `total_fabi` element within the same row each time a `req` or `was_perc` element changes:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').keyup(function()
    {
        // Find the row (if any) containing this input
        var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");

        // Find the .req, .was_perc, and .total_fabi elements *within* this row
        var $req = $tr.find(".req");
        var $was_perc = $tr.find(".was_perc");
        var $total_fabi = $tr.find(".total_fabi");

        // Do the update (probably better to use `text` than `html`)
        $total_fabi.text(parseFloat($req.val()) * parseInt($was_perc.val()));
    });
});
```

---

Re your comment below:

> sir how would i get the total computed generated by $total_fabi for my overall total? in php its just like $total += $total_fabi.. How can i do this in jquery?

You can do that with `each`:

```
var total = 0;
$(".total_fabi").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: sir how would i get the total computed generated by $total_fabi for my overall total? in php its just like $total += $total_fabi.. How can i do this in jquery? thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2593560: I've added to the answer.

Comment: does it means that variabble total will be my class in my <span class='total'>0</span>

Comment: @user2593560: No, it will be a variable in your code. You can then do with it what you like. I suggest stepping back from your current task and reading some basic tutorials on JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: :D sorry, im quite confuse due i have this code.. $total_fabi.text($answer);
$total_fabi.val($answer); That's why im asking. but i already solve what i wanted.. sorry.. Thank you very much @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know that `ID` attribute must be `unique` and you defined same ID many time.

You can use `class` instead of `ID` attribute.